# streamreader to read out lines of xml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

i would like to read out an xml file into a textblock and users can edit this text in the textblock and apply the append changes back to the xml file... i am currently stuck. This is what i've done so far:

```
    private void Editbuildstreams_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BuildstreamTextblock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        using (StreamReader srr = new StreamReader("initial.xml"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = srr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                BuildstreamTextblock.Text = line;
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the structure of the xml file:

```
<xml>
   <email>
..
   </email>
   <buildstream1>
      <path value="apple"/>
   </buildstream1>
   <buildstream2>
      <path value="pear"/>
      <path value="bananas"/>
   </buildstream2>
</xml>
```

the question are:

how do i read out the lines of the xml file?

i am only interested in obtaining certain parts of the xml file.how do i only get `<buildstream1>` & `<buildstream2>` to be read out?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
var originalDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var originalElement = originalDocument.XPathSelectElement("xml/buildstream1");
textBox.Text = originalElement.ToString();

// do changes in the text box

var newDocument = XDocument.Parse(textBox.Text);
var newElement = newDocument.Elements().Single();

// insert edited element
originalElement.AddAfterSelf(newElement);

// remove original element
originalElement.Remove();
originalDocument.Save(fileName);

// or

var resultXml = originalDocument.ToString();
```

Comment: I haven't worked with XDocument but the code you've shared is so elegant I might start...  +1

Comment: Yeah Linq to XML rocks. However, it is my understanding that it does _not_ work in streaming mode - can anyone confirm. From the question subject I (perhaps wrongly) gathered that this is a requirement?

Comment: with regards to your code, i see that only one element is being displayed when i use. if i have another element `"xml/buildstream2"` then how do can i add it into the textbox?

Comment: @jeremychan - I would suggest loading them into separate text boxes as this is easier. If you need to edit them in the same textbox, you need to concatenate strings to set `textbox.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not trying to read it like a text file and instead use a data adapter.  As long as the xml file is valid xml it works quite well.

You could then use a databound textbox, datagrid, combobox or various other tools depending on the options needed - further you wouldn't have to worry about users messing up the structure of the xml or writing your own logic to filter.

Here is some code samples that use roughly the same approach I'd take.  Googling will reveal hundres more.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/dataset.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at [XML Parsing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/xml_parsing.aspx) and [Easy XML Parsing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/nicexmlparsing.aspx)

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Using [XPathReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950778.aspx) (*this is a good article that, no doubt, you will want to read fully*). Example:

```
<xml>
   <email>
..
   </email>
   <buildstream1>
      <path value="apple"/>
   </buildstream1>
   <buildstream2>
      <path value="pear"/>
      <path value="bananas"/>
   </buildstream2>
</xml>
```

example

```
using System; 
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using GotDotNet.XPath;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            XPathReader xpr  = new XPathReader("input.xml", "//*/path@value");

            while (xpr.ReadUntilMatch())
                Console.WriteLine(xpr.ReadString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch(XPathReaderException xpre)
        { Console.WriteLine("XPath Error: " + xpre); }
        catch(XmlException xe)
        { Console.WriteLine("XML Parsing Error: " + xe); }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        { Console.WriteLine("File I/O Error: " + ioe); }
    }
}
```

Will print

```
apple
pear
bananas
```

Google for one of the many XPath tutorials

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to read the string and load into XmlDcument. This way you can easily find any specific elements easily.

```
private void Editbuildstreams_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BuildstreamTextblock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("initial.xml"))
    {
       reader.Read(); 
       doc.Load(reader);

       StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
       line.apend (doc.doc.GetElementsByTagName("buildstream1")[0].outerXml;

       BuildstreamTextblock.Text = line;
    }
}
```

similarly after manipulating them, you can assign changes back to original xml again by using XmlDocument object.